# input field using 'date' type - how to get date and convert to just 'YYYY/MM/DD'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the 'date' type on an input field and pre-submit jquery validates it is formatted correctly, should the calendar not show on their browser and they enter the date manually.

With the following code it always show that the input is an object and not as string/text.

I am hoping to get that date and convert it to just the date in US format, YYYY/MM/DD ready for other pre submit checks, like is the date in the past.

```
        function convertDateToYYYYMMDD(dateString) {
var type = typeof dateString;
alert(type);
            var formattedDate = dateString.toISOString();
        var d = new Date(formattedDate),            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),        day = '' + d.getDate(),         year = d.getFullYear();
        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
        var newDate = [year, month, day].join('-');

    return formattedDate;
    }


    var formContainer = $('form');
    formContainer.on('change', 'input[name="start_date"], input[name="end_date"]', function() {
    var currentDate = convertDateToYYYYMMDD(new Date());
    var startInput = formContainer.find('input[name="start_date"]');
    var endInput = formContainer.find('input[name="end_date"]');
        var startDate = convertDateToYYYYMMDD(startInput.val());            alert('given ' + startInput.val() + ' - nd ' + startDate);


    });
```

Comment: _"With the following code it always show that the input is an object and not as string/text."_ - so invoke the function with the _correct_ parameter then ...? Currently you have not even shown us where/how you are actually doing that.

Comment: `[year, month, day].join('-');` will output 2023-08-15 and not 2023/08/15 as your title asks. Which one do you want? If with dashes, then you have [hundreds](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+date+%22yyyy-mm-dd%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: `var newDate = [year, month, day].join('-'); return formattedDate;` ??? Perhaps you mean `var newDate = [year, month, day].join('/'); return newDate;`

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking it.  The date input gives you a string of `YYYY-MM-DD` and you want to convert it to `YYYY/MM/DD`.  All you have to do is replace the `-` with `/` and you're done.

```js
var $formContainer = $('form');
$formContainer.on('change', 'input[type="date"]', function() {
  var startDate = $formContainer.find('[name="start_date"]').val().replaceAll('-', '/');
  var endDate = $formContainer.find('[name="end_date"]').val().replaceAll('-', '/');
  console.log('Start: ' + startDate + ', End: ' + endDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="date" name="start_date" />
  <input type="date" name="end_date" />
</form>
```